# Modulo operator innaccuracy with large numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, modulo, floating-point-precision

I am writing some code to convert large integers from a thousand-based system (e.g. 1,234,567,891) to the Japanese system of ten-thousand (e.g. 12億3456万7891). In short, writing out numbers to a readable format in Japanese means splitting numbers into sets of four instead of sets of three.

The user inputs a number (var `innum`), and the modulo operator is used with divisors of 10,000's to pinpoint the 4-digit chunks where I would like the number marked with kanji (Chinese characters).

ex:
where `chobase`=10^12 (one-trillion), `okubase`=10^8 (100-million) and `manbase`=10000 (ten-thousand), and say the user input is 54234238524003:

```js
var cho = Math.floor((innum/chobase));            //returns 54
var oku = Math.floor(((innum%chobase)/okubase));  //returns 2342
var man = Math.floor(((innum%okubase)/manbase));  //returns 3852
var sen = (innum%manbase);                        //returns 4003
```

slap it all together as a string and... 54兆2342億3852万4003
Excellent- it works great.

However, when the integer tips into the ten-quadrillions (10^16), the modulo operator is no longer reliable.

example produced by code using the same logic as above (commas added for readability):

> input:  4,234,322,423,423,424,003 
>   output: 423京4322兆4234億2342万4000

This is incorrect, as the last four digits in the Japanese format should read 4003 given the input.

I realize that JavaScript numbers are floating point and that accuracy wanes as integers reach a certain size, so are there any suggestions on how to work around this for numbers of ten-quadrillions in size? (This is roughly the maximum size number I am aiming to convert). I saw php has an fmod() method for handling this type of situation, but I have been unable to find a javascript equivalent..

Comment: `4234322423423424003 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; // true` If you want to use numbers this big you will have to work with _Strings_

Comment: `4234322423423424003 === 4234322423423424000`. What did you say was your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider leaving them as *strings* if possible, then just using substring operations to manipulate them. Then you don't have to worry about whether they'll fit into a numeric data type.

By way of example, consider the following script:

```
function makeNum(num) {
    num = num.replace(/,/g,"");
    var markers = "万億兆京";
    var result = "";
    while (num.length > 4) {
        if (markers.length == 0) {
            result = "(未詳)" + num.substr(num.length-4) + result;
        } else {
            result = markers.substr(0, 1) + num.substr(num.length-4) + result;
            markers = markers.substr(1);
        }
        num = num.substr(0, num.length-4);
    }
    return num + result;
}

alert(makeNum("4,234,322,423,423,424,003"));
```

This first removes all commas then builds up the Japanese number section by section, using `markers` to select the correct separators. If your number is so big that it runs out of markers, I just use `(未詳)` instead which, if it *doesn't* mean "unknown", you can blame on the Japaneses-English online dictionary I used.

The result of that script is, as expected, a dialog box containing `423京4322兆4234億2342万4003`.

Comment: Handling this as a string makes things phenominally more simple. Thank you for the detailed response it works wonderfully.